# call function in angular ui tooltip

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Have used this code which invokes the user defined function : getTooltipText

```
<i tooltip=\"{{ getTooltipText(arg1) }}\"> </i>
....

//function definition

$scope.getTooltipText = function(arg1){
console.log(arg1); // prints undefined
....
return text;
}
```

But it is not working. Have even tried trinary operator, but no luck!! Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve with arg1? arg1 must be defined in your scope to be able to pass it as a parameter, tooltip will not pass it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `{{ getTooltipText(arg1) }}` ,may be you can use `ngMouseenter` and `ngMouseleave` directive.

```
<div ng-mouseenter="getTooltipText(arg1)">     
    <i tooltip="{{tooltip}}"></i>
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.getTooltipText = function(arg1){
   $scope.tooltip = "Your tooltip here";
}
```

[link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter)
(I am not sure about usage of arg1)

I took code from angular site and modified it a little just to demonstrate working of it:

```
   <body ng-app="" ng-controller="controller">
   <button ng-mouseenter="mouseOvver()" ng-mouseleave="mouseLeave()">
   when mouse enters
 </button>
 count: {{msg}}

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function controller($scope)
 {
   $scope.mouseOvver = function()
   {
     $scope.msg="Ok I got u";
   }
   $scope.mouseLeave = function()
   {
     $scope.msg="";
   }
 }
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: ng-init should only be used to run specific code that requires properties on the scope only available inside the context of the element. For example ng-repeat has a special property called $index but you might want to use it inside another scope. For more info check docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit