# Add a function call on div's tooltip

Tags: angularjs

i want to call a function on tooltip. Is it possible?

```
<div tooltip="toolTipForFetchPreviousOrders()">
```

Comment: Is `tooltip` a custom directive or part of separate module?

Comment: see this   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083708/call-function-in-angular-ui-tooltip/23083859#23083859)

Comment: <div title="toolTipForFetchPreviousOrders()">  </div> I want this code to call a javascript method toolTipForFetchPreviousOrders(). Instead it prints the function name value

Comment: you want to change title dynamically right ?

Answer (score 4):

try this, this may help you.
[Here is working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/xv7tws10/34/)

```
  <body ng-app="my_app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
   <div title="{{title}}" ng-mouseover="toolTipForFetchPreviousOrders()"> 
     Some Text
   </div>
  </div>
```

controller code

```
  var my_app = angular.module('my_app', []);

   my_app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title="qwerty";

   $scope.toolTipForFetchPreviousOrders = function(){
     $scope.title="qwerty12345";
   } 
 });
```

You can write any business logic in `toolTipForFetchPreviousOrders()`